# Android Studio not registering XMLs?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am currently having a headache with a really strange error.
Just a few hours ago, I was coding fine with no big errors.
However, when I hopped back on after eating dinner, I saw that there was a crazy amount of errors in my code, not seen at all before.

[image: A beautiful number of errors.]

I can see that all the errors pertained to references to XMLs, resources and layouts. The code was fine - Android Studio just couldn't link the references to the layouts.

Here is my Main_Activity class, to confirm that it is a problem with the Studio:
package com.example.denny.protoype2;

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        boolean StopTrue;
        final Button StopButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.StopButton);
        StopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Creates Dialog
                AlertDialog.Builder StopDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                StopDialog.setTitle(R.string.Stop_Title);
                StopDialog.setMessage(R.string.Stop_Message);
                StopDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.Yes_Button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        boolean StopTrue = true;
                        //Closes box
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                StopDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.No_Button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        boolean StopTrue = false;
                        //Closes box
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                StopDialog.setNeutralButton(R.string.Negative_Button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //Closes box
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }
}
```

The reason why I am asking is because I have tried to Clean and Rebuild my code, but it still refuses to fix the errors.

Anyone have a clue on why it did this?
Thanks!

Comment: Is `activity_main.xml` in your layout `res` folder?

Comment: Yes. Everything is in the right place. I know this because I have been using it just a few hours ago and it worked fine.

Comment: remove import android.R and try importing again

Comment: *That moment when someone casually throws a comment and it fixes everything you were getting headaches about for 10 hours.*

Comment: Ishwore, can you please put that in the answer section so that I can mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Check your R.java file in your Project.
it locates in ..\app\build\generated\source\r\debug\android\support\v